# Chinese character encoding in openshift 4 using java

Tags: java, character-encoding, openshift, openshift-4, chinese-simplified

I am unable to use chinese string as a file name in java. It is working as expected in local but when deployed in [OpenShift](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenShift), it is not encoding properly and appearing as ***?????***.

Code I have used for storing the Chinese characters.

```
String nonEnglishString = "你好，世界！";
String u = new String(nonEnglishString.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
```

I also tried this below environment variables in OpenShift.

```
LANG: UTF-8
```

But both of the approach are not working in OpenShift 4.

Comment: *nonEnglishString* might *already* be wrong. How did you create it? Also note that an empty `getBytes()` will return the *default platform encoding*

Comment: Assume that im storing ```String nonEnglishString = "你好，世界！"; ``` in the java code but still in openshift it is displaying as ????? @g00se

Comment: Your  first task is to determine whether the characters are  actually incorrect or merely displaying incorrectly, the latter perhaps due to inadequate fonts.

Comment: OK, with that assumption, it follows that for your code to work as is, the default encoding would *already* have to be able to encode Chinese characters. Your code implies that this is different to UTF-8. `System.out.println(java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset());` prints what?

Comment: @dilettante So is this an openshift issue? for not recognizing the chinese characters?

Comment: `new String(nonEnglishString.getBytes(), "UTF-8");` ← **Never do that.**  Strings have one and only one encoding.  You cannot change it.  If your Java program does not recognize the characters properly (which you can confirm by printing `nonEnglishString.codePointAt(0)`), the problem is the `-encoding` argument passed to (or omitted from) your javac invocation.

Comment: I have tried to print it using ```System.out.println(java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset());```. In server it is printing as  **US-ASCII** @g00se @VGR

Comment: *In server it is printing as US-ASCII* That definitely won't support Chinese

Comment: How to make it work in Openshift 4 server to recognize the chinese characters @g00se

Comment: I don't know Openshift unfortunately, but of course, any machine that would restrict you to ASCII is not a good thing ;)

Comment: OpenShift is basically an implementation of Kubernetes.  I don't know what 'deployed in OpenShift' means when it comes to text output. How are you viewing these characters?  Web browser pointing at something running in the container?  Shelling into a running container?  File you copied out of the container?  Output from some `oc` query?